# How to fit ordered logistic regression using svyglm()?

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to fit an ordered logistic regression glm for weighted data using `svyglm()` from the `survey` library:

```
model <- svyglm(freehms ~ agea, design = wave9_design, family=binomial(link= "logit"))
```

`freehms` is numeric ranging 1 to 5 (I've tried setting it as a factor) and `agea` is numeric too. I have many more variables, but didn't include them here for simplicity.

But for some reason I get the following error message:

```
"Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1"
```

I have looked at online examples, tutorials, and I just can't find what I'm doing wrong. I don't understand why Rstudio insists my independent variable be binary when I have specified the link function (logit) to address this very problem.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem ... the `ordinal()` package does a variety of cumulative-link models for ordinal data, but doesn't handle survey weights.  An ordinal response is not the same as a binomial response ... you did specify the logit link, but that's within the context of the binomial family.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply! I just noticed that the example I was using as a template was fitting a binary logistic model, not an ordered one. Regardless, my question is the same, as I have not been able to find any examples online.

Comment: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/catalogue/12-001-X20040016997 ; https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/insr.12218 (I have no idea about the implementation, but at least people are thinking about this ...)

Answer (score 5):

You want the `svyolr()` function in the survey pacakge.  Or the new `svyVGAM` package, which does a wide range of ordinal models.  `svyglm` doesn't fit this model because it isn't a generalised linear model.

For example

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dclus2<-svydesign(id=~dnum+snum, fpc=~fpc1+fpc2, data=apiclus2)
dclus2<-update(dclus2, mealcat=as.ordered(cut(meals,c(0,25,50,75,100))))

svyolr(mealcat~avg.ed+mobility+stype, design=dclus2)

library(svyVGAM)
svy_vglm(mealcat~avg.ed+mobility+stype, design=dclus2, family=propodds())
```